# UnicodeDecodeError in Python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, terminal

I am learning python3.6 and I wrote a simple program with the following code:

```
import os

with open ('USA 205-403.docx', 'rt') as in_file: # open file lorem.txt for reading text data

    contents = in_file.read() # read the entire file into a string variable

print(contents) #print the document
```

When I try running it in the terminal, this is the UnicodeDecodeError I get:

```
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> documentreader.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'documentreader' is not defined
>>> ^D
Jesses-MacBook-Pro-3:code for foundation data meduro$ python3.6 documentreader.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "documentreader.py", line 5, in <module>
    contents = in_file.read() # read the entire file into a string variable
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 14: invalid continuation byte
```

What is going on? When I run it in python2.7, it runs, but it spits encrypted text.

Ultimately, I want to turn this program into a file reader that looks for specific words and prints a certain amount of text surrounding those buzzwords

Comment: opening `lorem.txt` or `'USA 205-403.docx'`... In the comment it is given as `lorem.txt`...

Comment: Why are you trying to open a compressed binary file (`.docx`) as text? Open it using the "rb" flag... It works in Python 2.7 because the text type is `str` which is essentially a byte array. It would fail the same in 2.7 if you tried to decode it to `utf-8` which Python 3.4+ does automatically for you when trying to read text.